# Redirect Loop when logged out only

Tags: php, wordpress

I wrote a function that runs with the 'wp' hook and redirects if certain conditions are met (using Advanced Custom Fields), but it only works if I am logged in.  When logged out, it spits out a too many redirects error

```
    function swa_wc_product_redirect_to_post(){
    if ( is_product() ) :
        if ( get_field( 'redirect_to_post' ) == 1 ) :
            $redirect_post_url = get_permalink( get_field( 'redirect_post_id' ) ) ;
            wp_redirect( $redirect_post_url , 301 );
        endif;
    endif;
}
add_action('wp','swa_wc_product_redirect_to_post');
```

any ideas as to why it loops when logged out only?  Perhaps I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Wow - need a break on this project ;-)

Turns out that the post it was trying to redirect to was set to private - hence the loop.